# How to distribute elements of list of list with another elements list of list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists in Python like this 
`[['No1', 'No2'], ['No3', 'No4']]`
 and another list of lists 
`[['No10', 'No11'], ['No12']]`
I would like to get this list of lists
`[['No1','No2', 'No10'],['No1','No2', 'No11],['No3', 'No4','No12']]`

Comment: is this `[['No1', 'No2', 'No10', 'No11'], ['No3', 'No4', 'No12']]` the output that you want

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, I guess you need the following:

```
a = [['No1', 'No2'], ['No3', 'No4']]
b = [['No10', 'No11'], ['No12']]

print([i + [j] for i, sub in zip(a, b) for j in sub])
```

Output:

```
[['No1', 'No2', 'No10'], ['No1', 'No2', 'No11'], ['No3', 'No4', 'No12']]
```

Comment: Your answer is not what I want. The final list of lists should be like this `[['No1','No2', 'No10'],['No1','No2', 'No11],['No3', 'No4','No12']] `

Comment: @Henry I have updated my solution, can you check now